# "require 'mongoid'" is very slow

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Just opening irb and typing `require 'mongoid'` takes more than 5 seconds on my Macbook Air. Is it normal, and how can I speed this up ? It slows down a lot my Rails and Ruby apps launches.

I tried with versions 2.0.1 and 2.1.8, same result. Ruby version is ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

Thanks!

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

Comment: on my machine (ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]) it takes about 7 seconds :S

Comment: I'll try to write an answer with what I found

Comment: Macbook Air should have an SSD right? On my 2010 MacBook Pro w/ SSD (ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]), `require 'mongoid'` takes roughly 1 sec.

Comment: @James Chen: I have a 2009 Air with no SSD. Which version of mongoid do you have ?

Comment: @Blacksad: I tried 2.0.1 and 2.1.8. Both were ok.

Answer (score 0):

`require 'mongoid'`

Seems to be a call that takes long, indeed.

On my MacBook Pro (`ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]`) it's taking about 5-7 seconds (I've tested it on `irb`).

Note that one interesting message I got was:

> **Notice: C extension not loaded. This is required for optimum MongoDB
>   Ruby driver performance.   You can install the extension as follows:
>   gem install bson_ext
>
> If you continue to receive this message after installing, make sure
>   that the   bson_ext gem is in your load path and that the bson_ext and
>   mongo gems are of the same version.

Installing that gem **does not make the gem load faster** but it seems to improve speed overall.

Bottom line: try to make that require only once and at the start of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation Pablo. I already had bson_ext, it fastens data processing but not gem loading. I'll post my solution if I find any.